# XSLT for each help wrapping inside new element

Tags: xml

All,

I know that this is pretty simple to you but for me as a beginner I can't get it right. :( Please see below for the expected output. What should be the correct XLST? Thanks in advance.

Input XML:

```html
<map>
  <title>Lang's Commercial Leasing in Australia</title>
  <topic id="io1529956sl235024462" />
  <topichead navtitle="PRECEDENT FINDING LISTS" id="io2559290sl622242477">
  <topic id="io2558936sl197225260" />
  <topic id="io2558936sl197225261" />
  <topic id="io2558936sl197225262" />
  </topichead>
</map>
```

XLST

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
     <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
     <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
     </xsl:template>
     <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>
     <xsl:template match="map/topichead/topic">
          <comm.intro>
       <group>
       <xsl:attribute name="link"><xsl:value-of select="@id" /></xsl:attribute>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
       </group>
          </comm.intro>
     </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```html
<map>
  <title>Lang's Commercial Leasing in Australia</title>
  <topic id="io1529956sl235024462" />
  <topichead navtitle="PRECEDENT FINDING LISTS" id="io2559290sl622242477">
    <comm.intro>
  <group link="io2558936sl197225260">
    </comm.intro>
    <comm.intro>
  <group link="io2558936sl197225261">
    </comm.intro>
    <comm.intro>
  <group link="io2558936sl197225262">
    </comm.intro>
  </topichead>
</map>
```

Expected Output:

```html
<map>
  <title>Lang's Commercial Leasing in Australia</title>
  <topic id="io1529956sl235024462" />
  <topichead navtitle="PRECEDENT FINDING LISTS" id="io2559290sl622242477">
    <comm.intro>
  <group link="io2558936sl197225260">
  <group link="io2558936sl197225261">
  <group link="io2558936sl197225262">
    </comm.intro>
  </topichead>
</map>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
    <xsl:template match="map/topichead/topic">
      <comm.intro>
            <group>
            <xsl:attribute name="link"><xsl:value-of select="@id" /></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
            </group>
      </comm.intro>
    </xsl:template>
```

use two templates

```
    <xsl:template match="map/topichead">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <comm.intro>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </comm.intro>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="map/topichead/topic">
        <group link="{@id}">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </group>
    </xsl:template>
```

And you don't need the first template `<xsl:template match="/">` you have, the children of the document node are processed by the built-in templates.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I really appreciate your help.